# How to control the size of default image in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have included a default image of a file I uploaded on Flicker (which turns out to be huge), how can I control the size of it?

I added the default image using `:default_url => "URL Link"` in my models for pin
when I run `<% image_tag pin.image.url(:medium) %>` in `views/pins/index.html`, it only shrinks the size of other photos I upload while I create new pins. The default image is not showing a smaller size. So I assume there might be other codes needed to control the size of default image?

Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

:default_url is used if expected image is not present. default_url is not processed by paperclip. It is static url pointing to image location.

In your case, create default images with names and its size 
example, 
   **missing_icon.png** is at **app/assets/images/missing_icon.png**, then :default_url should be simply "/assets/missing_:style.png"
as

```
   :default_url => "/assets/missing_:style.png",
```

accessing

```
   my_model.attachment.url(:icon)
```

generated url

```
"/assets/missing_icon.png"
```

Comment: Hi aashiah, thanks for the comment. What if I am using a default image that is hosted on Flicker. The photo size(width and height) is far larger than the medium size I defined in the model. It's not hosted in my local assets yet. Is there a way to chop it?

Comment: resize the image to dimensions as per your need and upload to flicker. Now, set the path of image to :default_url. example :default_url => 'http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5445/missing_:style.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

While showing the image on view you can use :size, :width, and :height attributes of image_tag to control the size of the image to be displayed.

Examples:-

image_tag("icon.png", size: "16x10", alt: "Edit Entry")
Result to :-
`<img src="/assets/icon.png" width="16" height="10" alt="Edit Entry" />`

image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", size: "16")
Result to :-
`<img src="/icons/icon.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Icon" />`

image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", height: '32', width: '32')
Result to :-
`<img alt="Icon" height="32" src="/icons/icon.gif" width="32" />`